# Apple TV TVML Video Loop

Tags: ios, video, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

In html5 there is a simple way to loop a video. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp). I want to know if something like this exists for Apple TV's TVJS and TVML.

I can get it to loop in the javascript like this:

```
if(videoURL && event.type === "select") {
  var player = new Player();
  var playlist = new Playlist();
  var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);

  player.playlist = playlist;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
  }

  player.present();
}
```

However, this shows the video progress bar every time a new instance of the video starts, and this is not the functionality that I want. I want to loop continuously until exited.

Thanks in advance for any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not too far off, you had 1 issue :

```
player.present();
```

was suppose to be :

```
player.play();
```

here is the refactored code that works with tvml:

```
function playAndLoopVideo(src) {
player = new Player();
var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", src);
player.playlist = new Playlist();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
}

player.play();
}
```